# edit text setdigits programatically

Tags: android, edittext, input-type

Hola tengo un editText y necesita hacer el cambio entre abecedarios español, ingles, portugues
quiero solo cambiar los digitos que se pueden aceptar segun el abecedario seleccionado

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                android:inputType="text"
```

he intentado con `setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());`
pero solo acepta numeros

Comment: Que dígitos no se aceptarían en otro lenguaje??? :-|

Comment: por ejemplo en el español esta la ñ y en el ingles no y en el portugues en algunas palabras es necesaria ã u otras acentuaciones